# Get ASN Upstreams/Downstreams/Peers

Tags: bgp

I'm trying to gather the Upstreams/Downstreams/Peers of an ASN.

Lets take for example `AS8866`, I run this query on the ripe API

https://stat.ripe.net/data/asn-neighbours/data.json?resource=AS8866 more info on the query here https://stat.ripe.net/docs/data_api#asn-neighbours

and I get

```
...
"neighbour_counts": {
    "unique": 233, 
    "right": 100, 
    "uncertain": 60, 
    "left": 73
},
...
```

are `left` **upstreams** and `right` **downstreams** and how can I get the peers?

According to https://ipinfo.io/AS8866 this ASN has only 7 upstreams, but the RIPE API returns **73** marked as **left**.

The only resource I found on this topic is this email list https://www.ripe.net/ripe/mail/archives/opensource-wg/2017-March/000053.html

Comment: There really is no upstream or downstream when you are referring to peers. ASes peers with any other ASes they want to and can come to terms with. There really is not an upstream/downstream realtionship in many peerings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try caidas as rank dataset which contains AS links labeled with p2p/c2p:

http://data.caida.org/datasets/2013-asrank-data-supplement/

Also in general, business relationships between ASs are not public, but there are projects like the above trying to infer them based on BGP data.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing this RIPE RIS data with data I can verify, It seems that their data counts `left` as Upstreams/Transit providers and `right` as customers. It seems that `uncertain` may also be Bilateral peers on peering exchanges (however not all may show up).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know any other way/API I can query to get this kind of data?

Comment: Like you mentioned, the ipinfo.io API is quite good (Just need to sign up for a free account). You can also use bgp.he.net to visualise some of the data.